# App Store upload rejected by push entitlements problem

Tags: ios, push-notification, certificate, entitlements

I had to make some changes in my old iPhone app in XCode.

When uploading it to the App Store I get the following problem:

"ITMS-90078: Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment" entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service, make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a Distribution provisioning profile that includes the "aps-environment" entitlement. Xcode does not automatically copy the aps-environment entitlement from provisioning profiles at build time. This behavior is intentional. To use this entitlement, either enable Push Notifications in the project editor's Capabilities pane, or manually add the entitlement to your entitlements file."

I have done it that it said. I regenerated all my certificates and so on, but it does not fix my issue.

When I click Fix issue, it comes again and again.
[image]

Anyway, I had it in my entitlements file (it does not help even if I update it to production)

[image]

My certs are ok:

[image]

What should I do?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally, I could solve it:

I deleted all settings from Target / Build settings / Signing in XCode. I don't know exactly why it helped, probably it contained some settings from the past (note, it was not changed for years) that lead to this bug.

Although I leave my question here, hopefully it can save others day in the future.

Answer (score 6):

Enable **Push Notifications** in Signing & Capabilities Section in Xcode.

Answer (score 5):

I got the problem in xcode 11.3, then I fixed by this way:

1. Check and note your app Capability in Target -> Signing and Capabilities
2. Find and remove file name .entitlements in xcode bundle
3. Search and delete the value of "CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS" in target -> build settings -> search "CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS"

[image]
4. Add your app Capability again in Target -> Signing and Capabilities -> All