# Firebase Analytics iOS/Unity Push Notification?

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine

I installed Firebase Analytics and I'm getting this in my binary from Apple:

> ITMS-90078: Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears
>   to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app
>   signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment"
>   entitlement.

​
I don't have push notification in my game and it seems like it's coming from Firebase. Did I install something I shouldn't have? I don't want Push Notification.

Answer (score 0):

Check your project's build settings. 
Use Xcode to clear out those settings and try to rebuild.

See here > [App Store upload rejected by push entitlements problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56578904/app-store-upload-rejected-by-push-entitlements-problem)

*Update:*

1. Create a new project with firebase.
2. compare the configs of the new project and your project with the warning. I'm betting you have an unnecessary flag or setting that can be removed, from the firebase plugin.

Comment: It's weird. I only get a warning to fix it but Apple accepts the binary.

Comment: same warning with a new project @Mistergreen?

Comment: I asked the same question on firebase google group and got an answer where the firebase code might imitate push notifications, and triggers notification detection from Apple.

Comment: if you have tested it, and can confirm that is the correct, answer then please add a new answer to your question and mark it correct. answering in the comments of an incorrect answer is hard for some users to spot. thanks.

Comment: I don't see how fire-base or anything else could initiate it without you coding it, and therefore knowing that you were calling apple push notifications (unless you forgot you wrote it). I suspect that this is not the answer in your case, but its good to bring it up it might help somebody else.